# How does the Navigation activity stay open all the time?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to do something with an activity, similar to the Google Navigation that is already included on the device.

Google navigation stays open and keeps track of where you are, where you were going, time to destination, time traveled, etc. It doesn't close or lose where it's at.

How exactly is this achieved? In what way can I do the same thing? I understand how the activity life cycle works, and that I need to do something `onStop` or `onPause`, but other than that I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a Service in your app that can continue to run in the background.  Check out the [Service documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html).

Answer (score 0):

An activity cannot do background work when the user navigates away from it (e.g. back, home or open another activity). What you should do instead is to start a *[service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)* that runs in the background and does the work, independent of any activities.